# Django UnitTest check for Permission with self.user.has_perm in test_views.py for View(LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin, ListView)

Tags: django-views, django-testing, django-users, django-unittest, django-login

I Basically followed the Mozilla How-to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Testing#Views_that_are_restricted_to_logged_in_users

To get a Complete Picture here you can see the corresponding urls and view in **views.py** and **urls.py** below:

```py
path('contexts/', views.ContextListView.as_view(), name='contexts'),
```

```py
class ContextListView(LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Context
    paginate_by = 10
    permission_required = 'catalog.view_context'
    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.user.is_staff:
            queryset = Context.objects.all()
        else:
            user = self.request.user
            queryset = Context.objects.filter(name=user)
        return queryset
```

I have Created two Users in two different ways that should do the same.
One of the ways is commented out.

```py
class ContextListViewTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        number_of_contexts = 25
        number_of_extensions = 25
        # test_user1 = User.objects.create_user(username='testuser1')
        # test_user2 = User.objects.create_user(username='testuser2')
        # test_user1.set_password('1X<ISRUkw+tuK')
        # test_user2.set_password('2HJ1vRV0Z&3iD')
        test_user1 = User.objects.create_user(username='testuser1', password='1X<ISRUkw+tuK')
        test_user2 = User.objects.create_user(username='testuser2', password='2HJ1vRV0Z&3iD')
        test_user1.save()
        test_user2.save()
```

While a Simple Login test seems to Work:

```py
    def test_login(self):
        c = Client()  # Login
        login = c.login(username='testuser1', password='1X<ISRUkw+tuK')
        self.assertTrue(login)
```

**Testing For a specific Permissions does not:**

```py
    def test_logged_in_uses_correct_template(self):
        self.c = Client()  # Login
        self.user = User.objects.get(username="testuser1")
        login = self.c.login(username='testuser1', password='1X<ISRUkw+tuK')
        response = self.c.get(reverse('contexts'))

        # Check for HTTPResponseForbidden
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 403)

        # Check for Permission the User don't have but need to display that view.
        # self.assertFalse(self.user.has_perm('view_context', self.user.userprofile))
        # self.assertFalse(self.user.has_perm('view_context', self.user.profile))
        # self.assertFalse(self.user.has_perm('view_context', self.user))
        # self.assertFalse(self.user.has_perm('view_context', self.user.user_permissions))
        self.assertFalse(self.user.has_perm('view_context', self.user.user_permissions))
```

The Test `self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 403)` will pass because the Logged in User don't have the Permission `catalog.view_context`

After that i want to explicitly check that the User doesn't have that permission `catalog.view_context` with `self.assertFalse(self.user.has_perm('view_context', self.user.user_permissions))` but i constantly get Errors like `bool/user object/ XYZ has no Attribute profile/userprofile/user/user_permissions`

I also looked into this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10103291/4238752 and this https://stackoverflow.com/a/33294746/4238752
But no matter what I try it continues to throw the same Exceptions and Errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think i got it Working now like this:
**test_views.py**

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
from django.test import TestCase
from django.urls import reverse
from catalog.models import Extension, Context
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Permission
from django.test import Client


class ContextListViewTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        number_of_contexts = 25
        number_of_extensions = 25
        test_user1 = User.objects.create_user(username='testuser1', password='1X<ISRUkw+tuK')
        test_user2 = User.objects.create_user(username='testuser2', password='2HJ1vRV0Z&3iD')
        test_user1.save()
        test_user2.save()
        # Create 25 Contexts
        for context_id in range(number_of_contexts):
            Context.objects.create(
                name=f'test{context_id}.de',
                countryprefix=f'{context_id}',
                cityprefix=f'{context_id}',
                number=f'90096{context_id}',
                extensionsfrom=f'0',
                extensionstill=f'Surname {context_id}',
                portscount=f'Surname {context_id}',
            )
            # Create 25 Extensions per Context
            for extension_id in range(number_of_extensions):
                Extension.objects.create(
                    username=f'test{context_id}.de_{extension_id}',
                    password=f'Password{context_id}',
                    firstname=f'Max{context_id}',
                    lastname=f'Mustermann{context_id}',
                    callerid=f'Max Msutermann <{context_id}>',
                    extension=f'{context_id}',
                    )

    def test__for_login_restriction_permission_and_template(self):
        # Create Client
        self.c = Client()
        # Try to call the Restricted View as Anonymous
        response = self.c.get(reverse('contexts'))
        # Check for Login Promt Redirection
        self.assertRedirects(response, '/accounts/login/?next=/catalog/contexts/')

        # Get Userobject
        self.user = User.objects.get(username="testuser1")
        # Login with the Client
        login = self.c.login(username='testuser1', password='1X<ISRUkw+tuK')
        # Check our user is logged in
        self.assertTrue(login)
        # Check for our username
        self.assertEqual(self.user.username, 'testuser1')

        # Try to call the Restricted View as logged in User again but without Permission
        response = self.c.get(reverse('contexts'))
        # Check for HTTPResponseForbidden
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 403)

        # Check for view_context Permission the User don't have but need to display that view.
        self.assertFalse(self.user.has_perm('catalog.view_context'))
        # now add the permission
        self.user.user_permissions.add(Permission.objects.get(codename='view_context'))
        # refetch user from the database
        self.user = User.objects.get(pk=self.user.pk)
        # Print all Permissions to Console / Should now include view_context
        # print(self.user.get_all_permissions())
        # Check for view_context Permission the User should now have
        self.assertTrue(self.user.has_perm('catalog.view_context'))

        # Try to call the Restricted View again but with Permission this time
        response = self.c.get(reverse('contexts'))
        # Check that we got a response "success"
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

        # Check we used correct template
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'catalog/context_list.html')

    # def test_pagination(self):
```